# Getting a background-img in a keyframe

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am trying to figure out keyframe animation and in doing so, I wanting to incorporate multiple pictures. For example, every 10% increment I will want to change out the image to show someone running.

I have tried adding in a `background-img` to my demo and it will not do show the image at all. I searched for this, but the only results I found were from 2013 and they said it wasn't possible then, but I figured in three years this may have changed.

If this is not possible, how would you recommend I change the image every 10% or so?

Here is what I have been trying so far:

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/brain.jpg");
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
    animation-direction: normal;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:500px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:500px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:500px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:500px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `background-size`

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bu7tgz5y/

Comment: Awesome! That did it for me! Thanks.